# types cannot be converted when validating the users input for an integer

Tags: java

I am trying to validate a user's input and check if the inputted number is an integer. Id like to throw them an error message if the number isn't an integer. I am getting stuck on the line `Integer.parseInt(number);` Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sums {

    public static int number;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int evenSum, oddSum = 0;
        int posInt;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a postitive integer: ");
        int number = input.nextInt();
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(number);
            System.out.println("Value entered is " + number);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println(number + " is not an integer.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the `int number = input.nextInt();` to `String number = input.next();` and it works.

Comment: Thank you! it does.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need explicitly to convert your number to an integer, `Scanner.nextInt()` already does that for you, i.e. `Scanner.nextInt()` scans the next token of the input as an `int`. So just remove the line "`int number = input.nextInt();`" from your code. In general, `Integer.parseInt()` is preferable when you want to convert a `String` representation of an `Integer` value as a signed decimal integer. For instance, if you would have used `Scanner.nextLine()` instead of `Scanner.nextInt()`, then it makes more sense to convert it to a signed decimal integer if you want to perform subsequent operations using that integer value.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that when you call `Integer.parseInt(number)` you are trying to parse the variable `number` which is an `int` and not a `String`. This means that you are doing the error checking on a conversion from an `int` to an `Integer` and not a `String` to an `Integer`.

To fix this, input a string instead of a number, then perform the conversion on the string, not the number.

```java
...

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int myNumber;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a postitive integer: ");
    String numberString = input.nextLine();
    try {
        myNumber = Integer.parseInt(number);
        System.out.println("Value entered is " + myNumber);

        // do what you want with the number

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println(numberString + " is not an integer.");
    }
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
int number = input.nextInt();
```

The variable **number** is already an int, that is why you can not hand it over to the method. The method requires a String.

If you want to use the method like you did, you should use

```java
input.next()
```

as argument because it returns the input as String and initialize number within the try block, e.g.

```java
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        int evenSum, oddSum = 0;
        int posInt;
        System.out.println("Enter a postitive integer: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            number = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
            System.out.println("Value entered is " + number);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Not an integer.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bug here is `int number = input.nextInt();`

When you want to convert a `String` to a `primitive` datatype we use `class.parseXXX(String)`
You see I have written `String` in the `function` `.parseXXX(String)` Cause it takes `String` as a parameter and nothing else
So lets read your code

```
Integer.parseInt(number);
```

Here its `.parseXXX(int)` and clearly its not matching `.parseXXX(String)`
So in order to give `String` as parameter, you have `accept` String as input from user.

**Replace this** `int number = input.nextInt();` **with** `String number = input.next();`

So  now below code is valid cause its in `.parseXXX(String)`

```
Integer.parseInt(number);
```

Changed code:

```
        int evenSum, oddSum = 0;
        int posInt;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a postitive integer: ");
        String number = input.next(); // <-- Changed
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(number);
            System.out.println("Value entered is " + number);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println(number + " is not an integer.");
        }
```